# Tab layout problem

Tags: android

![enter image description here][1]

I want to make a tab layout application, in which there are four tabs. Now I would like to set multiple layouts in one tab.

For example, the example below of a tab layout they make four tabs,

[image: I like turtles]

Now in the first tab (Timeline) make a button that give next page link,
press next button and other layout display in the first tab (timeline tab). So what thing do I need to do?

Comment: pls provide image instead of link.. edit your question...it could attract more people

Comment: i got message "Earn more than 10 reputation to post images."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the ActivityGroup. Read *[Android tabactivity nested activities](http://blog.henriklarsentoft.com/2010/07/android-tabactivity-nested-activities/)*, and you will get what you want.

Comment: The link appears to be broken now.